# Problems calling stored procedure in MongoDB with C#

Tags: javascript, c#, mongodb

I have a problem, as stated in title, calling stored procedure in MongoDB (system.js) from Visual Studio (C#).
I'm testing mongodb's functions cause of a university project, I started with this javascript function:

```
function (x, y) {
    return x+y;
}
```

and called it with following code in C#:

```
var cmd = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{ eval: \"function(1,2)\" }");
var result = db.RunCommand(cmd);
var intResult = result["retval"].ToInt32();
Console.WriteLine(intResult);
```

and everything is ok, result given is correct.
I then tried to "evolve" my function with this one:

```
function (word) {
    len = word.length;  
    return len;
}
```

and trying to call it with:

```
    string word = "hello world!";
    var cmd = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{ eval: \"function({"+word+"})\" }");
    var result = db.RunCommand(cmd);
    var intResult = result["retval"].ToInt32();
    Console.WriteLine(intResult);
```

but it gives me the error "Command eval failed: Failed to call method", tried with:

```
var cmd = new JsonCommand<BsonDocument>("{ eval: \"function({word})\" }");
```

but in this case it says "word" isn't defined.
Can anyone suggest me some documentation about this argument and help me with my problem? I'm having some trouble with this JS calling from C# (same doing functions in mongodb that query the DB).
Thanks in advance

Comment: IIRC, you don't need to encapsulate the parameter with braces, so try single quotes: \"function('word')\"

Comment: works perfectly! thanks! Do you have any documentation about this argument?

Comment: Sadly not, and I did pour through the documentation on Mongo's website to sanity check. I think it's just the nature of the Java language rather than a mongo specific thing. Glad it's fixed though. :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "stored procedure" in MongoDB, and "server side JavaScript execution" is not a stored procedure. Most importantly **[`eval`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/eval/) is Deprecated** and WILL BE REMOVED from the API so your code will cease to function. There is no valid reason for JavaScript execution that cannot actually be better achieved in the native language implementation or refactoring. Perhaps instead you should present what you "think" you need to really do instead of a trivial "test case" function.

Comment: My main goal is to create functions on server side, then call them from C#. Searching I found main method to do so is `eval`, what should i use instead?